# Why does the size of my div change when the vertical scrollbar appears?

Tags: html, css

When I change the height of a page so that the vertical scrollbar appears, a div element on the page stretches out and a blank block appears at the bottom of the page. The current site is here:

http://cliqups.herokuapp.com/

What should I do to stop this resizing of the div? Should I just disable the vertical scrollbar altogether?

For posterity, I've added a few screen shots.

Without scrollbar:
[image]

With scrollbar:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your culprit within the /assets/application-67b0f50f40b31242c0515ffd40544866.css file the @media-queries css kicks in at a certain screen height.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 855px)
    div#wrapper div.container div.sign-up {
    margin-top: 271px;
    }
```

find this line and take out the margin-top: 271px; and you should see the extra spacing disappear. You won't need to disable the scrollbar. I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I inherited this code and I'm still ramping up on the more advanced aspects of CSS. Time to go read up on @media. ;-)